# Replace the trailing zero's of the date fields in the line

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, perl

This is my input

```
"004|B20A|2008-09-01 00:00:00.000|C|2008-09-01 00:00:00.070|4277"
```

My output should be

```
"004|B20A|2008-09-01 00:00:00.0|C|2008-09-01 00:00:00.07|4277"
```

Comment: It it just this one line or is this just a sample line out of a much bigger file? Is processing by `perl` mandatory or can it be any suitable tool? Is this the only modification you need to do on the file?

Answer (score 0):

with a file

```
perl -ip -e 's/(\.\d+?)0*(\|)/$1$2/g' "$F"
```

or with a pipe

```
echo "$V" | perl -pe 's/(\.\d+?)0*(\|)/$1$2/g'
```

Comment: This turns the `.070` in the second timestamp into `.0`, though, not into `.07`.

Comment: DonHolgo fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it as:

```
perl -F'[|]' -lae 's/\.\d+?\K0+$// for $F[2], $F[4]; print join "|", @F'
```

(here assuming the *date fields* are the 3<sup>rd</sup> and 5<sup>th</sup>).

Answer (score 0):

How about this?:

```
perl -pe 's/(\.\d+?)0*(\D)/$1$2/g'
```

Your sample input includes double quotes at the beginning and end, so presumably there'll never be a floating-point number at the end of the line.